# Can I use 'jerking' here?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, word-choice

> The monster stands, transfixed, staring at the dead police officer. It
> starts ***jerking*** at his body as if to check that he really is dead. It
> then pulls him out of the chair and starts dragging him across the
> floor.

The monster is half human half animal. The intended meaning is that the monster starts shaking the body without pulling it anywhere. Can I use "***jerking***" and should it be followed by "***at***"? Or does it sound like the monster can't control its hands?

Comment: No, it's not very good to use ***jerking*** here. ***To jerk*** is close to ***to twitch, to shiver, to sneeze,*** etc. - both syntactically and semantically these are essentially ***intransitive*** verbs. That's to say it's more natural to say ***something jerks*** (all by itself) rather than ***someone jerks something***. Which latter usage normally only occurs where "someone" has ***total control*** over how "something" moves (a puppeteer controlling his puppet using strings, for example). Better in your context would be something like *It starts **tugging at** his body*.

Comment: (Note that the optional preposition in *tugging / pulling / poking **at** something* strongly implies ***NOT causing "something" to move to a different physical location***.)

Answer (score 2):

"Yanking" or "tugging" would be more appropriate here, as they are actions done by one thing to another. "Yanking" is more violent, "tugging" is rather gentle.

> Beth quickly grabbed at Cody and yanked his arm, preventing him from falling off the cliff.
>
> The girl tugged at/on her father's sleeve, trying to get his attention.

"Jerking" is typically used to describe an involuntary motion originating from the object/person.